# What does it mean to be “cashiered?”

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context

I was reading up on the [Dirlewanger Brigade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirlewanger_Brigade) (a scummy bunch of Nazis even by Nazi standards) and came across this line:

> “…cut-throats, renegades, sadistic morons, and cashiered rejects from other units…”

What exactly does “cashiered” mean in this context? I assume it does not refer to someone emptying a cash register...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means to be dismissed from the army in a dishonorable manner - the Wikipedia article ([Cashiering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cashiering)) covers the meaning, with historical examples:

> A ritual dismissal of an individual from some position of responsibility for a breach of discipline.

The word is from the Flemish *kasseren* (to dismiss, discard), unrelated to "cash".

Answer (score 1):

Seems like it means someone was dishonorably discharged [[Cambridge Dictionary]](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/cashiered):

> “to officially dismiss (= remove from a job) a person from a military organization, especially making them lose their honour at the same time.”